# Fire event depending on click event on data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 tabs with the same data-attribute but its value changes.

```
<li>
    <a href="#tab1"
       data-set="set1">{{{text}}}</a>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="#tab2"
       data-set="set2">{{{text}}}</a>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="#tab3"
       data-set="set3">{{{text}}}</a>
</li>
```

Depending on which of those elements you clicked on, another element has to change its background.

So:

```
$('a[data-set="DYNAMIC SET"]').on('click', function(e) {        
    $('.eight-box').css({background: '/path/image'});        
});
```

What can I do to make it dynamic and not only use if-else or switch-case?

Lets say: `set1` sets one background. `set2` sets another background and so on. So the path to the image will change too.

Comment: then its easy to have class selector

Comment: @Omi I can use a class but I am using that data-attr for a reason. So I would like to use the same data-attr. Or how is it with a class?

Comment: How are you mapping the background image per set?

Comment: @JesseKernaghan Lets say: `set1` sets one background. `set2` sets another background and so on. So the path to the image will change too.

Comment: So, `set1` one could be `background: "/path/image1"`, `set2` is `background: '/path/image2' and etc`

Comment: Apologies, perhaps I wasn't clear: where is that path defined? In the `href`? In another `data-attr`?

Comment: @JesseKernaghan sorry I pasted as I have in the document. Is a handlebars document. I already fix my question. See the code above. It is only used to take the user to the proper tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will attach the event to any `<a>` that has a `data-set` attribute; you can then read the attribute using `$(this).attr('data-set')` to do whatever you need to based on its contents.

```js
$('a[data-set]').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevents the <a> from navigating
  var dataset = $(this).attr("data-set");
  console.log("You clicked on ",dataset);

  // do whatever you need based on that value, for example:
  $('.eight-box').css({background: '/path/'+dataset+'.jpg'});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a href="{{href}}" data-set="set1">{{{text}}}</a></li>
<li><a href="{{href}}" data-set="set2">{{{text}}}</a></li>
<li><a href="{{href}}" data-set="set3">{{{text}}}</a></li>
<li><a href="{{href}}" data-set="set4">{{{text}}}</a></li>
<li><a href="{{href}}">(No dataset on this one)</a></li>
```